# Cambiar variable ID en firebase con la libreria Python Firebase

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase

Quisiera saber como puedo ingresar datos a firebase para que la estructura quede por ejemplo asi:

```
/Usuarios/Administradores/Angel/Nombre
```

y no esto:

```
/Usuarios/Administradores/-LGze8xg3oWiYgzWi6F1/Angel2/Nombre
```

es decir no quiero que esto : `-LGze8xg3oWiYgzWi6F1` se agrege a la jerarquia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
from firebase import firebase


s = "hola que hace"
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/')

result = firebase.post('/Usuarios/Administradores',{'Angel2':{'Nombre':s}})
#result = firebase.get('/Usuarios/Administradores/Angel1',None)
print(result)
```

pero con este codigo genera el : `-LGze8xg3oWiYgzWi6F1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías acceder a la ruta directamente con el metodo `put` y desde ahi agregar las propiedades que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
result = firebase.put('/usuarios/administradores/javier', {'nombre': 'Javier'})
```

Con `put` puedes escribir o reemplazar datos en una ruta de acceso definida. Por otro lado con el metodo `post` se genera una lista nueva con una clave única.

Comment: Gracias funciono perfecto

Comment: sabes si hay algun limete de datos ¿?